# Errors were encountered while processing: man-db

Tags: dpkg

I get this error when I use `apt-get upgrade & apt-get autoremove` and on every `apt-get [Something]..` and when I try to install applications too:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
man-db
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Solved by executing this command:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a   
 Thank you.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` helps if there are unmet dependencies

Comment: Do `sudo apt purge man-db`, then install it again.

Answer (score 25):

No solution mentioned in the answers worked for me and I tried a solution mentioned [here on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1712079), executing the command

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all [deb file path]
```

and that worked.

Comment: What is [deb file path] ?

Comment: That is the path of `.deb` file

Comment: Thanks for replying, and sorry for my ignorance.   I had this problem, and I don't know what .deb file you are referring to (I solved the problem using the "delete *.dat" file approach below, but I didn't like that much (like, whoa, this seems hacky)

Comment: I strongly will not recommend to use the `--force` key unless a user fully understands what he is doing. Such options exist only for situations where the user knows that the error will not lead to any serious problems, one must not use it carelessly

Comment: worked great for `man-db` issues.

Comment: This worked for `libkf5kdegamesprivate1` and `ksudoku`. (For context: The problem happened after I added the neon ppa to kubuntu and `dist-update`d everything)

Comment: `dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-ck5V9z/11-linux-tools-common_5.4.0-165.182_all.deb': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 16):

Please read the comments below. **This may be a dangerous command to run on your system and create an unrecoverable state.** (the lines have been commented out to prevent copy-and-paste sysadmin'ing).

---

Simple and **working** i tried it !!

```
sudo -s
# cd /var/cache/debconf
# rm *.dat
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: I think this might lead to issues as it contains various config files.

Comment: instead of `rm *.dat` I think you should go for `mkdir tmp` `mv *.dat tmp`

Comment: Did not work in my case, I had to `dpkg --purge --force-depends ...` some files in order to restore sane functioning.

Comment: This produces an error: **Errors were encountered while processing:
 debconf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

Comment: This set of commands did not work if drivers (for example) are not configuried properly.

Comment: I additionally had to do `apt --fix-broken install` in order to fix unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

You may also want to know that you can use `dpkg --audit` to see what the actual problem is.

If the output is something like:

```
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during installation. 
They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages that depend on them) 
to function properly:
  gcdemu A GNOME panel applet to control CDEmu daemon

The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 cdemu-daemon CDEmu daemon
 cdemu-client A simple command-line client to control CDEmu daemon

The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time. The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 transmission-daemon lightweight BitTorrent client (daemon)
 vhba-dkms VHBA virtual host bus adapter module
```

You could run the command: `dpkg --configure <packagename>`

```
 dpkg --configure cdemu-daemon
```

In order to

```
Reconfigure an unpacked package. 
If -a  or  --pending  is  given instead of package, all unpacked but unconfigured
packages are configured.
```

Furthermore you could use:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --reinstall install gcdemu
```

To fix the packages that are in a mess.

Examples from here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1502826.html

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Agreed, however identifying the problem is part of the solution. I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Much better! upvoted!

Answer (score 5):

You have to run those commands with sudo preceding them so they can be executed with super user credentials Example:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove "NAME OF PACKAGE HERE"
```

Comment: i run sudo -s when i first start terminal.

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
this solved the problem
Thanks

Comment: you made my day

Answer (score 5):

*community wiki answer - solved by OP*

This problem was resolved by running the following terminal command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
```

Comment: **sudo: unable to execute /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: Permission denied**

Comment: ≻ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
Unknown option: a
Usage: dpkg-reconfigure [options] packages

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted `/var/cache` in a misguided attempt to clean up (like I did), this might fix the issue (it did for me):

```
sudo mkdir /var/cache/debconf
```