# Can not see Google Chrome in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I am installing Google chrome in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

I followed following steps.

1) Add Key:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

2) Set repository:

```
echo 'deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

3) Install package:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

This installation done successfully.

NOW the issue is that when i open google-chrome i can not see the open window of browser, But in left bar i can see that the google chrome is open.

Help me to solve this
Thank you

Comment: @Kevy Do you have any idea why this error coming.

Comment: what's the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: i am getting this error every time when i am trying to install or remove some thing.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104493/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-man-db)?

Comment: yes i tried, now i am not getting this error and chrome is installed BUT i can not see open tab of browser

Comment: do try `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome/*; google-chrome`.

Comment: one popup opne with two checkbox with option for set default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66327/discussion-between-kevy-and-p-m).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66329/discussion-between-p-m-and-kevy).