# Ubuntu 16.04 restarts itself when it's about to load the desktop on startup

Tags: 16.04

Each time I start my computer, when the desktop is loading, the computer restarts, but if I switch to a TTY by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it doesn't restart.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 already, but the problem persists. I don't think it's a hardware issue because Windows works just fine.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does choosing `Try Ubuntu without installing` from your install DVD/USB get all the way to the desktop without restarting your computer?

Comment: it works when i use try ubuntu from a usb, with out any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do update/upgrade commands in the terminal that you can start on the login screen?
Had the same issue, solved the same way as if I have a blue screen.
Got it from the links.

[Stuck on blue screen while booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839279/stuck-on-blue-screen-while-booting-the-system)

[Errors were encountered while processing: man-db](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104493/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-man-db)

Comment: tried the upgrade/update commands even installed a graphics card driver but still running into the same problem